# Disable custom routing in asp.net mvc application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes

I am pretty new to asp.net and the application I am working on used custom routing to call each class. Is there some way I can get rid of this so it can default back to the normal way of automatically routing based on class names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just go to RouteConfig.cs file and remove all the custom routing and keep only the default routing there.